# Immediately Invoked Function Expression with Angular 1 throws exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I was reading the [Angular Style Guid](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#iife) and it recommends using Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE). When I converted my app to use it, I started getting an [exception](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=documentationApp) at runtime everytime I ran it. The exception was because it is not able to find the app module.

I've made sure that the following files are included in the correct order in my layout page (asp.net project)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/toolkit.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/DocumentationApp.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Controllers/DocumentationListController.js"></script>
<script src="~/App/Services/TopicsService.js"></script>
```

If I remove the IIFE implementation it all works without any errors. What am I doing wrong? Is this potentially because I'm using JQuery in my shared asp.net layout? The `ng-app` directive is used in my View, after the layout has ran though.

### IIFE version

> DocumentationApp.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('documentationApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
        .config(configureRoutes);

    function configureRoutes($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/Templates/index.html',
            controller: 'DocumentationListController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
        })
    }
})
```

> DocumentationListController.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('documentationApp')
        .controller('DocumentationListController', DocumentationListController);

    function DocumentationListController(topicService) {
        var viewModel = this;
        viewModel.name = 'bob';
        topicService.get().$promise
            .then(function (response) {
                viewModel.model = response;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
})
```

> TopicsService.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('documentationApp')
        .factory('topicService', getTopics);

    function getTopics($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/documentation/GetTopics');
    }
})
```

### Non-IIFE version

> DocumentationApp.js

```
angular.module('documentationApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config(configureRoutes);

function configureRoutes($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/app/Templates/index.html',
        controller: 'DocumentationListController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
    })
}
```

> DocumentationListController.js

```
angular
    .module('documentationApp')
    .controller('DocumentationListController', DocumentationListController);

function DocumentationListController(topicService) {
    var viewModel = this;
    viewModel.name = 'bob';
    topicService.get().$promise
        .then(function (response) {
            viewModel.model = response;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

> TopicsService.js

```
angular
    .module('documentationApp')
    .factory('topicService', getTopics);

function getTopics($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/documentation/GetTopics');
}
```

Comment: I see no IIFE here. You're missing the `()` part that actually invokes the function: `(function(){}())`;

Comment: That fixed it - thanks! I completely missed that part.

Comment: so common issue :) seems like every1 faced it one day